# How to switch turns on a tic tac toe board using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am currently working through the oden project tic tac toe project. I am struggling with trying to get the display controller function to change turns upon initial button click.

I have tried making a variable and calling the displayController function with the variable. But i don't really know where i am going wrong. So if i could get some help, that would be greatly appreciated.

const displayController = () => {

```
  currentPlayer = player1;
  const switchTurn = () => currentPlayer === player1 ? currentPlayer = player2 : currentPlayer = player1

  return{switchTurn}
};





//Module function for controller
const markBoard = () => {
  
  let turn = 0;
  let cells1 = document.querySelectorAll('.test');
  
  cells1.forEach(cell => {
   cell.addEventListener('click', e => {
    if(cell.textContent === ""){
       
      cell.textContent = "X"
      const playerUno = displayController();


      playerUno.switchTurn();

      alert('player2s turn')
  }

  else if(e.target.value !== ""){
     alert('please click another box');
  }
   })
  })

  return {
   markBoard
  }
 }
```

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a little hard to follow, but I think this answers it?

I've never seen a function being called by simply returning itself (`return {markBoard`), so I'm not sure if that part is working or not.  If you're not getting clicks at all then delete it, and add `markBoard()` outside the function.

Your displayController function is just all kinds of wrong.  Most importantly, it'll always return the same result if you start with `currentPlayer = player1`, so currentPlayer needs to be initially determined somewhere else.  Otherwise you don't even need the function, just set it initially with `let playerUno = "player1"` and switch turns with `playerUno = playerUno === "player1" ? "player2" : "player1"`.

So I believe your code should look something like this:

```
const markBoard = () => {
  
  let turn = 0; //this isn't used?
  let cells1 = document.querySelectorAll('.test');
  let playerUno = "player1"
  
  cells1.forEach(cell => {
   cell.addEventListener('click', e => {
    if(cell.textContent === ""){
       
      cell.textContent = "X"
      
      playerUno = playerUno === "player1" ? "player2" : "player1";

      alert(`${playerUno}s turn`)
  }

  else if(e.target.value !== ""){
     alert('please click another box');
  }
   })
  }) //I'd also put the click event in it's own function to avoid this mini-callback hell
 }
markBoard();
```